# How far do potatoes really need to be from tomatoes to prevent disease/blight?

Tags: tomatoes, organic, potatoes, sweet-potato, blight

How far do potatoes really need to be from tomatoes? Is ten feet with a row of peas in between sufficient?

Also, do sweet potatoes count as potatoes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They should all be 3 feet from one another, the tomato plants and the potatoes. Its not to prevent blight, but to prevent disturbing the roots of the tomatoes if you dig up some potatoes nearby, and to prevent blossom end rot caused by insufficient water/calcium availability for the tomatoes. The greater distance also makes it less likely that any plant will shade another - both these plants require sun to crop well.

As for sweet potatoes, no, they don't count as potatoes - they're related to Ipomea (morning glory), so a vine and they take up a lot of room sprawling over the ground, so you need 3 feet either side of one plant for those.